# Option key not Working on Win Keyboard

Tags: mac, keyboard, windows

I've an annoying problem with a windows keyboard on mac.
I already changed the keys in keyboard preferences, but I cannot use the option key.

**case**: windows = option
I have no access to chars like ~[]|{}

**case**: alt = option
I have access to these chars

Do you have an idea why it is not working?

(keyboard: HyperX Alloy FPS RGB)

thanks

Comment: I'm not quite certain what you're trying to do. Using a Windows keyboard on Mac it's usually just simpler to leave it at defaults - Win key acts as Cmd, alt is option. That way Alt-Gr acts almost correctly as ctrl/alt. It would anyway be useful to know what macOS & precisely which language version of the keyboard you have & what language layout is it set to. []{} usually have their own keys on a US or UK keyboard.

Comment: You might want to check with the people who make that keyboard?